# Problems with Facebook Iframe - links dont work (php site with DB)

Tags: php, html, facebook, iframe

I am trying to put a site within an `iframe`, but the links do not work.
The site was done in php accessing a database where are the "addresses" of links.
I tried everything I could find on the internet.
I tested in a html page and it worked, but within the `facebook` link does not work
**ps:** the site opens but only the links that do not work

In the page the code for links and URLs is that

```
     <?php
for($i = 0; $i < count ( $produto ['IDGRA'] ); $i ++) {
$style = ($i % 5) == 4 ? 'style="margin-right:0"' : '';
echo '<li class="produto" '.$style.'>';
echo '<a href="'  . $produto ['LINK'] [$i] . '">';
echo $produto ['IMAGEM'] [$i] ['ARQUIVO'] [0];
echo '</a>';
echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: can you show the generated html?

Comment: sure! <iframe src="http://illuminari1.sslblindado.com/Facebook/produto1" width="800px" height="800px;" sandbox="allow-forms" >

Comment: generate html is that ?

Comment: Yeah.. but anyway doesnt work .. i tried , targer parent and top too.. no sucess

Comment: If I put that iframe in [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vfhPZ/1/), it works fine. Not sure what I can say now.